# How to maintain image transparency in the video editor

Tags: transparency, video-sequence-editor

I have a render I've made of a model in blender and it has a transparent background, I've saved it as a PNG (which should keep the transparency) and imported it into the video editor. Once its imported it has a black background and the only way to change the transparency seems to be the opacity, but I don't want the whole image to be transparent. I've tried changing the film settings to allow for transparency but that hasn't made a noticeable difference.

[image: Blender image render saved as a PNG.]

[image: Blender video editor imported image, the blacked out region should be transparent, like in the previous image.]

How can I get the transparent parts of my image to be transparent again?

edit:

[image]

Comment: Would you mind showing the whole program window so that we can see at least a few settings?

Comment: Its currently at the default settings for the video editor when its selected from the blender launch window. The only things Ive changed is properties > render > film >transparency on.

Comment: btw its version 4.0.2

Comment: The _Film_ > _Transparent_ makes the scene background transparent for scene rendering, it has nothing to do with rendering image strips in the _Video Sequence Editor_. Please show the whole editor window, especially the _Preview_ window and the _Output Properties_ for the video file. Or upload your scene here: https://blend-exchange.com (best with the image sequence packed inside the file) and follow the instructions there to edit it into your question so we can examine the file ourselves.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann updated post with image as requested

Comment: The _Video Sequence Editor_ settings look okay. The first image shows the _Render Result_ with transparency... have you checked the rendered files if they actually have transparency? Because the transparency shown in the _Render Result_ is how it was rendered, not how it was saved. If you have saved the PNGs for example as _Color_ > _RGB_ instead of _RGBA_, the transparent background will be black because you saved the image without alpha transparency.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann OMG, thank you, yep I saved it wrong.

Comment: By the way, if you are not going to overlay this sequence inside Blender on some background showing through the transparent parts, rendering it like this as a video will get you a black background as well, because the default encoding settings are saving a video file that does not support transparency (see the missing _RGBA_ in the output properties). Only the _Video Codec_ "QT rle / QT Animation" and one or two others support transparency.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the *Use Alpha* option under the *Image* or *Movie* strip properties in the *Video Editor*? This should preserve the transparency of your PNG image during the import process.

Comment: The previous commenter already helped me fix the issue, my png didn't have an alpha channel to read